# Ignoring headers in log files being indexed in Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk

Being relatively new to Splunk (ver 6) and even newer to Reg-ex, I have log files that I and trying to index that have a header than I need to ignore. There are 6 header lines. The first 4 all begin with * and the last two are blank lines. I'm assuming they are just carriage returns. I'm looking for help with the regular expression that will ignore these lines in the transforms.conf file when adding the data. Below is an example from the log file I want to add:

```
*******************************
***    This is a Header     ***
***   07:32:06 Tue Jan 07   ***
*******************************


Jan-07 07:32:06 SERVERNAME:somedatainfo
Jan-07 07:32:06 SERVERNAME:moredatainfo
```

Answer (score 1):

On the forwarder or indexer you can set the sourcetype for the file that is being monitored.

```
# in inputs.conf
[monitor:///path/to/your/file]
sourcetype=new_sourcetype
```

On the indexer, you can get rid of the first lines like this:

```
# in props.conf
[new_sourcetype]
TRANSFORMS-test=ignore_header

#in transforms.conf
[ignore_header]
REGEX=^\*\*\*+
DEST_KEY=queue
FORMAT=nullQueue
```